# Expiring a form after submission

Tags: php, forms, curl, paypal, submit

I have a developed a membership based website which after a PayPal external payment is made directs the user to a secure login form by using PayPal's 'tx' code from a cURL operator.

My trouble is, that after this secure form is echo'd and has been filled and submitted the user can easily click the BACK button on their browser and create another account agin, which is no good, as I only want accounts to be created after an individual payment.

Could anyone give me any insight into how I should code my form to make sure the form expires should they click'BACK' or how I could expire the specific 'tx' code in the url on submission?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Simon.

(my current process is PayPal Payment > *reg.php?tx=xxxxxxx* and fill echo'd form > reg_script.php(which directs to login when successful.) > login.php)

Comment: generate and use a unique id (timestamp based) for each creation

Comment: Hi Ulrich, Thanks for responding, do you mean create a timestamp and post it to the database? And then call a function before the form to check it wasn't previously submitted? A brief code example would be much appreciated if you have the time? Thank you.

Comment: yes create your user in the DB with status (inactive|active) or reg_paypal (with value 0|1) + the unique-id... so that you can get more control on it. remember it is better to store every information.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich! That's great, will get on it now.